# Listener is getting executed each time the Activity starts

Tags: android, listener

```
public class example extends Activity { 
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    PhoneStateListener myListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceStateChanged (ServiceState serviceState) {

             // Some stuff

        }
    };

    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTelephonyManager.listen(myListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);

}
```

Here is the code.
Problem is Listener is getting executed each time the Activity starts rather than only on event listen.
Please let me know how can I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the network service state indeed is changing quite frequently. This might make it seem that the listener is being called as soon as the Activity starts (which is when the listener is getting attached).

Comment: Thanks sparkymat, No I tried using emulator, That's not the case for sure.

Comment: Do not rely on the emulator, especially for telephonic behavior like network service state. Always prefer testing on an actual device.

Comment: Ya, I have tested on actual device also. Each time I open the application, the listener is getting executed.